# What's wrong with this old Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

When activating this old Wordpress Plugin I get several errors. The plugin used to work fine until I had to replace the deprecated replace_function feature. The plugin creates a form in the media gallery and outputs a selection of images in a widget.

The Plugin:

```
<?php

class FreigeistRandomGalleryWidget extends WP_Widget
{
  function FreigeistRandomGalleryWidget()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'FreigeistRandomGalleryWidget', 'description' => __('Displays random images from the gallery.','freigeist') );
    $this->WP_Widget('FreigeistRandomGalleryWidget', 'Freigeist Random Sidebar Gallery', $widget_ops);
  }
 
  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' , 'amount_images' => '') );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $amount_images = $instance['amount_images'];
?>
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:','freigeist'); ?></label> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></p>

<p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('amount_images'); ?>"><?php _e('Amount Images:','freigeist'); ?></label> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('amount_images'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('amount_images'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($amount_images); ?>" /></p>

<?php
  }
 
  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['amount_images'] = $new_instance['amount_images'];
    return $instance;
  }
 
  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
 
    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
 
    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;
 
    // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE



if( isset($instance['amount_images'])) {$amount_images = $instance['amount_images'];} else {$amount_images = 5;}

$sidebar_random_array = array();

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => '9999',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array  (
            'key' => '_show_in_gallery',
            'value'=>true
        )
    )


         );
$loopb = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $loopb->have_posts() ) : $loopb->the_post(); 
    array_push($sidebar_random_array, get_the_ID());
endwhile;

// Shuffle order of images in gallery
shuffle($sidebar_random_array);

// Only take the ... images for the display
$sidebar_random_array = array_slice($sidebar_random_array,0,$amount_images);

foreach ($sidebar_random_array as &$value) {



    $value = '<div class="gallery-sidebar-div"><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($value,"large")[0].'" data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($value)[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title($value).' '.__('by','freigeist').' '.$artist.'"></a><a href="'.get_site_url().fr_gallery_url().$value.'"><span><i>'.get_the_title($value).'</i>, '.get_post_meta($value, 'artist_name', true).'</span></a></div>';
}
unset($value,$img,$title);

echo implode('',$sidebar_random_array);



  }
 
}





add_action(
    'widgets_init', 
    function() {
return register_widget("FreigeistRandomGalleryWidget");

    }
);



?>
```

The Errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 passed in /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61 and at least 2 expected in /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:162 Stack trace: #0 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php(61): WP_Widget->__construct() #1 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('FreigeistRandom...') #2 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/freigeist-random-gallery-widget.php(119): register_widget('FreigeistRandom...') #3 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): {closure}('') #4 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/widgets.php(1809): do_action('widgets_init') #7 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): wp_widgets_init('') #8 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #9 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-settings.php(578): do_action('init') #11 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-config.php(88): require_once('/customers/3/c/...') #12 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/customers/3/c/...') #13 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/customers/3/c/...') #14 /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/index.php(17): require('/customers/3/c/...') #15 {main} thrown in /customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 162
```

If anyone could explain me what the errors mean and how to fix them, I would be very grateful!

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to the constructor for the `WP_Widget` class, which your widget extends. It's expecting two arguments and you're not passing it any. I haven't used WordPress for many years now, so am no longer familiar with the architecture. Hopefully someone else can provide further insight.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that your plugin is passing too few arguments when instantiating an object that now expects those values when it's created.

Assuming this is older code that no longer worked with newer versions of wordpress, the mechanics of this old plugin code are not sending the newer requirements when the WP_Widget is initially registered.

Look for what line 162 in this file is looking for `/customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:162` and ensure that whatever is passed is available in `/customers/3/c/f/domain.xy/httpd.www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61`

If you're using outdated WordPress plugin or core code, it's going to be much more difficult to track down what isn't working and to modify it appropriately.  If you're looking to re-author an outdated plugin against the latest WordPress Core, you need to figure out what changed in the core and how to modify your plugin example appropriately.

That error is telling you that you're missing arguments which it now expects. To me, that says the calls within the plugin are deprecated by changes to the WordPress core.  I can only assume what your environment is at this point.